# Using Euler formula to prove maximum number of lines in planar graph without triangles

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Im trying to prove a planar graph without triangles with $ n \ge 3$ points has at most $2n-4$ edges. I want to solve this using the Euler formula, $n+f=m+2$. I've come to the conclusion that $f\le$ $m/2$, however when I plug this into the formula I get:

$n+ m/2 \le m+2$

$m \ge 2n-4$

Seeing as this is the exact opposite of what I want, I'm sure that the inequality signs are wrong, however I just don't understand why. Thank you!

Comment: Well, how did you come to the conclusion that $f \ge m/2$? It is there that your mistake lies.

Comment: Apologies, I meant f ≤ m/2, and that's what I also used to calculate the first inequality  (n+m/2 ≤ m+2), however it gives me the result that m is bigger than the maximum number of lines

Answer (score 1):

Since $n - m + f = 2$, we have $f = 2 + m - n$.

We can use this to take $f \le m/2$ and replace the $f$ by $2 + m - n$, getting $2 + m - n \le m/2$.

This rearranges to $n + m/2 \ge m + 2$: the opposite of the inequality you got.

Comment: Can you please explain why the inequality symbol is that way, and why for example m/2 isn't bigger than 2+m-n?

Comment: See my edit; does this help?